# Excel re-order columns using a list

Tags: vba, excel

I want to reorder some columns in excel, using a list of values that are in M1 to M10 and that have the name of the headers and the order in which they should be ordered.

I have this script that works if I use:

```
v = Array("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country")
```

However when I changed to

```
v = Range("m1:m10").Value
```

It doesnt work, giving the following message:

> Subscript out of range.

Here is the whole code:

```
Sub Reorganize_columns()
' Reorganize Columns Macro
'
' Developer: If you want to know, please contact Winko Erades van den Berg
' E-mail : winko at winko-erades.nl
' Developed: 11-11-2013
' Modified: 11-11-2013
' Version: 1.0
''v = Array("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country")
' Description: Reorganize columns in Excel based on column header

Dim v As Variant, x As Variant, findfield As Variant
Dim oCell As Range
Dim iNum As Long


v = Range("m1:m10").Value
For x = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
findfield = v(x)
iNum = iNum + 1
Set oCell = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=findfield, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not oCell.Column = iNum Then
Columns(oCell.Column).Cut
Columns(iNum).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: You need `findfield = v(x,1)` as an array from a range will automatically be 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `findfield = v(x,1)` as an array from a range will automatically be 2D.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you alot!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use collection instead of array, but if you wish, you can assign values like that:

```
Dim i As Long

ReDim v(0 To 0)
For i = 0 To 9
    ReDim Preserve v(0 To i)
    v(i) = Range("m1").Offset(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `ARRAY()` function, you are generating a 0-based array.  If your code works using this function to make `v`, then replace this single line of code:

```
v = Array("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country")
```

with these 5 lines of code:

```
Dim v(0 To 9) As String, i As Long

    arr = Range("M1:M10")
    For i = 0 To 9
        v(i) = arr(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
```